# Tensorflow CPU warning for tensorflow-gpu-nightly package

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

I'm receiving the following error when I start my tensorflow session:
 Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2

I have installed the GPU nightly version for windows and have CUDA GPU toolkit 9.0 installed. This is a CPU warning and shouldn't come as I have a GPU and using that to run tensorflow models.

Following is my GPU usage(task manager) while training models:[GPU Usage link - task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8pYV.png)

Comment: This is a warning, not an error, you can just ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

A Tensorflow binary always has CPU code, no matter it supports GPU or not. This warning will show up on any reasonably new CPUs with pre-built Tensorflow binaries.

A GPU-enabled binary contains GPU kernels for Tensorflow OPs, such that many computation-heavy OPs could be offloaded to GPU. But there are always some OPs that does not have GPU kernels, and most of all, there is always code that runs on CPU just to start the program.

Pre-built Tensorflow binaries are not built with instructions supported on newer CPUs in order to be able to run (almost) everywhere.

The only way to have a binary to leverage all capabilities your CPU has to offer is to build from source, either natively or cross-compiling with proper target. And only then these warnings will be gone.